# Почему не удаляет второй элемент Python

Tags: python

Всем привет. Есть задачка. в функцию передается два значения, список и число.
Нужно удалять все элементы списка пока до тех пор, пока число списка не будет ровно числу переданным вторым параметром в функцию

```
def remove_all_before(items: list, border: int) :
    # your code here
    index = 0
    for i in items:
        if i == border:
            break
        else:
            print(f"Удаляем {i}")
            input(" ")
            del items[index]
            index = index + 1

    return items


print(list(remove_all_before([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)))
```

Написал вот такую функцию, но он почему то не удаляет второй элемент и возвращает результат

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

а должен

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Используйте `continue` вместо `break`.

Comment: Во-первых, результат не такой, какой пишете вы. Во-вторых, после удаления 1 индекс у 2 становится 0. Это информация к размышлению.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я рекомендую не изобретать велосипед, а использовать возможности стандартной библиотеки:

```
from itertools import dropwhile


data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
element = 3

result = list(dropwhile(lambda x: x != element, data))

print(result)
```

Что касается того, почему не работает ваш код - внутри цикла никогда не стоит удалять элементы последовательности, по которой проходит этот цикл. При удалении все последующие элементы смещаются и цикл проскакивает через один элемент. Кроме того, у вас из-за такого смещения index будет указывать уже не на тот элемент, который вы ожидаете.

Answer (score 2):

вот код без использования сторонних модулей и с проверкой на выход за пределы списка
 `len(items) - border`ето индекс с которого будет срезан список и возвращен как результат роботы функции
`if len(items) <= border:` ето проверка на выход за пределы списка если border меньше либо равно длине списка , в таком случае функция вернёт пустой список проверка нужна чтобы не возвращался список срезанный по негативному индексу или  вернулся пустой список  если длина списка ровна border

```
def remove_all_before(items: list, border: int) :
    if len(items) <= border :
        return []
    else:
        return items[len(items)-border::]
    
print(remove_all_before([1,2,3,4,5],3))
```

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_all_before(items: list, border: int) :
# your code here
index = 0
for i in items:
    if i == border:
        continue
    else:
        print(f"Удаляем {i}")
        del items[index]
        index = index + 1

return items
```

print(list(remove_all_before([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)))

Comment: И какой умник поставил плюс? Минус за нерабочий код.